# Codeigniter Database Error Number :1048, it says Column 'I' cannot be null even though the column is not null

Tags: codeigniter, sql-insert

here is the controller
[**Controller : Data.php**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wO9H.png)
[**Controller : Data.php**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBNuk.png)

here is some the models
[**Model : PelangganModel.php**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORrS3.png)

here is the database
[**Database**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2PZh.png)

Comment: Please do not post image of code and instead post the code directly inside the question as text

Answer (score 1):

When editing the field in the Structure tab, look for the "NULL" checkbox. When un-checked, this is the equivalent of the NOT NULL statement.

If you uncheck this property then it means that it is not null.

[image]

once check that checkbox and try it once.